# Polyfills for event listeners not working- get TypeError for IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I get this TypeError error in Internet explorer from window.dispatchEvent. I have tried adding numerous polyfills for angular but nothing seems to work. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.[click here for SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz397.jpg)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? when does this error occurs? please provide a code snippet as well...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Esp. pay attention to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) part.